# Is there a term for a grammatical construction like "Exhibit A"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, proper-nouns, ordinal-numbers

Is there a term for names that consist of a noun or noun phrase followed by an ordinal letter or numeral? For example:

- *Exhibit A*
- *The Land Before Time IV*
- *Patient Zero*

Perhaps *ordinal proper noun* or *ordinal titular appositive* would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Is more specific than or the same as *King John, Section C, House Atreides*? I would call those **titular appositions**. You use an apposition to mention something's (semi-)title in a proper noun.

Comment: I was specifically asking about a term that would apply to *Section C* but not *King John* or *House Atreides*. So I suppose that that term would be more specific than *titular apposition*. But thanks for your answer; I wasn't familiar with *titular apposition*.

Comment: @MaxRadin: I made it up, but grammatically it's the same construction, I should say.